# Check that file is fully downloaded by FTP

Tags: bash, shell, ftp

I have a task in which I want to handle error occurred in FTP downloading, For which I used the `wget` command to download a file via FTP and once the download is complete, compare downloaded filesize with FTP file size.

For that, I have the code as follows. My question: is this the correct method?

```
# fetch file details from the server and extract only number from the return value

FileSizeOnServer=curl --max-time 10 -u $FTP_USER:$FTP_PASSWORD --head $FTP_Path 2>&1 | grep "Content-Length:"
echo "Present File Size Details:" $FileSizeOnServer

FTP_File_Size=${FileSizeOnServer#*: }
echo "FTP_File_Size:$FTP_File_Size"

# fetch only size of local file size

DownloadedFileSize=`stat -c %s /home/pi/Desktop/ABCD.txt`
echo "DownloadedFileSize:$DownloadedFileSize"

# compare local and ftp file size

if [ "$DownloadedFileSize" -eq "$FTP_File_Size" ]; then
    echo "Size matched"
else
    echo "File Size doesn't match Start Downloading again"
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

You definitely need more quoting of parameter expansions.  Notably, `$FTP_PASSWORD` may well contain characters that are meaningful to the shell:

```
FileSizeOnServer=$(curl --max-time 10 -u "$FTP_USER:$FTP_PASSWORD" \
                   --head "$FTP_Path" 2>&1 | grep "Content-Length:")
```

I'm not sure it's a good idea to redirect standard error there - you want errors to be visible, not piped into `grep`.

I'm not sure there's much value to the size comparison, though - `curl` should exit with non-zero status if it didn't transfer the whole file, so we should just use it directly:

```
if ! curl -u "$FTP_USER:$FTP_PASSWORD" "$FTP_Path"
then
    echo "Failed to download" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Or even simply

```
set -e
curl -u "$FTP_USER:$FTP_PASSWORD" "$FTP_Path"
```

Answer (score 2):

> I have a task in which I want to handle error occurred in FTP downloading, For which I used wget command to download a file from FTP and once the download is complete, compare downloaded filesize with FTP file size.

Your attempt is approach to solve this problem, and it's not a very good one.

The `wget` command exits with failure if the download isn't complete.
So one better, but still naive option is to check the exit code of `wget`, and use the `-c` flag to continue downloading a partially downloaded file, for example:

```
while ! wget -c ...; do
     echo "Download failed, trying again..."
done
```

The issue you describe is quite common, and `wget` itself has more options to help.
For example you can specify with the `-t` flag the number of times `wget` should re-try downloading a file until it succeeds.

> ```
>    -t number
>    --tries=number
>        Set number of tries to number. Specify 0 or inf for infinite
>        retrying.  The default is to retry 20 times, with the exception
>        of fatal errors like "connection refused" or "not found" (404),
>        which are not retried.
> ```

Other related options may also be interesting, for example `--waitretry` (in `man wget`).

---

Do not use `` `...` ``, it's obsolete. Use `$(...)` instead.